# how can i pass data from one component into another component in react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-component

I am working in chat application, i want to display name of selected users just like telegram and other chat apps. i have 2 components  to display all users available and  to display selected user. i already fetched the users data from firebase and displayed it in . how can i display name of selected user in the  component.

this is what i tried out so far.

**Chats.js**

```
function Chats() {

    const userRef = firestore.collection('users');
    const [users] = useCollectionData(userRef, {idField: 'uid'});

    const passdata = () => {
        //
    }

    return (
    {users && users.map((user) => (
                <Sample onClick={passdata}>
                    <Photo><img src={user.photoURL} referrerpolicy="no-referrer" /></Photo>
                    <Info>
                        <UserName>{user.displayName}</UserName>
                    </Info>
                </Sample>
            ))}
    )
}
```

**SelectedChat.js**

```
function SelectedChat() {
    <Profile>
        <Photo><img src={} referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/></Photo>
        <UserName>{}</UserName>
    </Profile>
}
```

[this is the screen shot of the chat app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vKpC.jpg)

i.e. i am using firebase

Comment: Send it in `passdata` and it will pass to `SelectedChat`?

Comment: could you please explain it well.

Comment: How your `passdata` function is rendering `SelectedChat`?

Comment: both are independent Component. SelectedChat is in a file called SelectedChat.js, and Chats is in a file called Chats.js. and i render both of the in another Component Called Main.js. i am not using passdata yet.

Comment: I recommend reading up on React Contexts. There are many examples and tutorials out there to get you started.

Comment: If you have something shared, like the users, it's better to fetch it in the main.js and pass it along to other components, if the you have many nested components, go for state management systems like redux or context

Answer (score 0):

So If I understood you right, both components are independant from one another yet you need to pass the selected user name from the users list to the selected chat component.
In this case the best approach is to use a service.

### 1. create the service

in your project directory create a usersService.js file and paste the below code in it.

```js
export class usersService = () => {
          constructor() {
            this.user = null;
          }
};
```

### 2. register/get selected user

inside the return brackets add the following function that will save the selected user from your chats component.

```js
export class usersService = () => {
          constructor() {
            this.user = null;
          }
          
          setCurrentUser(user) {
            this.user = user;
          }
      
          getCurrentUser() {
            return this.user;
          }
};
```

### 3. register user name in Chat.js component

in your Chat.js file import the service `import usersService from './path'` then in your `passdata` method you can register the selected user and pass it to the service.

```js
const passdata = (user) => {
  usersService.setCurrentUser(user);
}
```

and in your html: `<Sample onClick={passdata(user.displayName)}>`

### 4. get selected user name in SelectedChat.js component

import the service like you did in Chat.js component then you can use the `getCurrentUser()` method to get the selected user:

```js
function SelectedChat() {
    <Profile>
        <Photo><img src={} referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/></Photo>
        <UserName>{usersService.getCurrentUser}</UserName>
    </Profile>
}
```

I think this will solve your problem, best of luck